# Equivalent of Hyper-V's VMConnect in VMWare Products?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

Hyper-V has a useful utility  VMConnect.  It lets you connect to a guest machine at the hardware level,  like a KVM.  Is there a VMConnect equivalent in the VMWare toolset?

Comment: Lazy question - zero attempt to self-research - we expect better here.

Comment: @Chopper3 Don't be so quick to judge.  Didn't intend for this to come across as lazy, rather as a straight forward and clear.  If you look at my profile on SO, you'll see I'm a contentious contributor.  You ever find you just cannot find the right thread or phrase?  That's the case for me here.  It made me thing others might be in same boat.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called VMWare remote console, is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

https://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/vmware_remote_console_vsphere90.pdf